# Calling a function which has multiple outputs

Tags: matlab

This is a simplified version of my code:

```
function [] = test9(~)
    t = 1;
    a = fcn(t);
  % b = fcn(t)
    function [x y z] = fcn(t)
        x = 1*t;
        y = 2*t;
        z = 3*t;
    end
end
```

When this is run, `a` is equal to the value of `x`. This is presumably because it's the first output of `fcn(t)`.

How would I edit line 4 to obtain the value of `y`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are expecting three outputs, hence you should specify three returned variables when you call the function. i.e.

```
 [a,b,c] = fcn(t);
```

Consider also that just one function call is sufficient.